# Является ли вводным "вроде бы"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Он(,) вроде бы(,) уже проснулся". Является ли тут оборот "вроде бы" вводным и стоит ли его выделять запятыми?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы = будто бы. Никаких запятых здесь не должно быть, так как это не вводные слова, а частицы или сравнительный союз

Answer (score 5):

ВРОДЕ БЫ - частица, не требует постановки знаков препинания.